# При нажатии на кнопок "развернуть" и "свернуть в  окно" не меняется размер блоков.

Tags: javascript

вот код javascript

```
<script>
window.onresize= function ()
{
var a = window.innerWidth;
var obj = document.getElementById("div1");
var wobj = document.getElementById("div2");
if (a<1220){
var win = (a-920)/2;
if(win<0){win=0;}
wobj.style.margin = "0 0 0 "+win+"px";
}
if(a<960){
var mak=a-500;
obj.style.width = mak+"px";
}
}
</script>
```

какое событие нужно использовать чтобы при нажатии на кнопки "развернуть" и "свернуть в  окно" скрипт тоже запускался а не только при ручном изменении размера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так

```
window.onload=init;
window.onresize=resize;
function init() {
    document.getElementByID('clickme').onclick=resize;
}

function resize ()
{
var a = window.innerWidth;
var obj = document.getElementById("div1");
var wobj = document.getElementById("div2");
if (a<1220){
var win = (a-920)/2;
if(win<0){win=0;}
wobj.style.margin = "0 0 0 "+win+"px";
}
if(a<960){
var mak=a-500;
obj.style.width = mak+"px";
}
}
```

а если под свернуть/развернуть имеется ввиду кнопка окна. так оно и так должно запускаться. ну и ещё вместо js можно воспользоваться css media в вашем случае.

Comment: в том то и дело, нажимаете на развернуть а блоки оказывается такими какие были при маленьких размерах окна. и не понятно что вы сделали.

Comment: какой браузер ? Ну и ещё раз - это делается через css.

Comment: chrome.через css, как мне кажется, нельзя добиться того, чего можно с помощью javascript. Ведь нельзя через css начать уменьшать блок с определенного пикселя?

Comment: кнопками "Развернуть" и "свернуть в окно" называю кнопки окна браузера!

Comment: у меня в chrome все работает, вот [демо](http://jsbin.com/OcUyoLi/2/)

Comment: Там у вас вообще ничего нету, кроме ТЕСТ

Comment: а сорри, гадкий jsbin демо подменил вот - http://jsbin.com/OcUyoLi/2/edit